# CGContextClearRect with circle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am creating an app in which i am trying to clear the `rect` of `UIImageView`. I have achieved this with `CGContextClearRect`, but the problem is that it is clearing `rect` in square shape and i want to achieve this effect in round shape.

What i have tried so far:

```
UITouch *touch2 = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint point = [touch2 locationInView:img];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[img.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.frame.size.width, img.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGRect cirleRect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 40, 40);
CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 50, 0.0, 2*M_PI, 0);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextClearRect(context,cirleRect);
//CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 30, 30));
img.image =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Check this answer, may this will work for you.




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061200/how-to-draw-a-concentric-circle-in-iphone/%22Click%20Here%22

Comment: Check this answer with a running example that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27796085/1381708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but your clipping arc isn't being created correctly. You are creating it at a fixed position which is why it doesn't really work - except it does, if you click in the top left corner.

If you want to see it working try this:

```
- (IBAction)clearCircle:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    UIImageView *imageView = self.imageView;
    UIImage *currentImage = imageView.image;
    CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat rectWidth = 40.0f;
    CGFloat rectHeight = 40.0f;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:imageView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageViewSize, YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [currentImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    CGRect clippingEllipseRect = CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - rectWidth / 2, touchPoint.y - rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, clippingEllipseRect);

    CGContextClip(ctx);

    CGContextClearRect(ctx, clippingEllipseRect);

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Which creates a clipping ellipse (in this case a circle) in the rect 40 x 40 centred at the touch point.

You can see this in an example project on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/dotimage) which you can [download for yourself](https://bitbucket.org/abizern/dotimage/get/master.zip) to try

Comment: Its working, but the problem is that there is black color behind image. And i have another image behind image, not black color? so what's this happening

Comment: That's a completely different question - but as a hint, you should look at image masks.

Comment: `CGContextClip(ctx);` Saved my life!